# How do you write the word 'wow' as if someone is dragging the sounds out longer than normal?

Tags: dialogue

I am writing about a person daydreaming. She is looking into space and says the word 'wow'. How can I write it to convey she is dragging the word out?

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities. Here are a few:

> Woooow!
>
> Wo-ow!
>
> Woaaaow!
>
> [Wowser(s)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/wowser)!
>
> Wowwww!

Depending on how they intonate and pronounce it.

Answer (score 1):

The importance of the emotion you are desirous of conveying in your story is inversely proportional to the effectiveness of textual games. So if whatever emotion the character is expressing is of little importance, then spelling out the word to convey their feeling is sufficient.  If it is very important to that moment in the story or who we see the character, then spelling games are the least effective solution.

The technique works in movies and graphic novels/comics where the actor or the artist is also able to embed emotional queues that support the emotion. In prose, different techniques are available.

You can show the physical sensation. Try saying it yourself, as you imagine the character says it. How does your throat feel? Do you run out of breath? Its it explosive or drawn out -- I'm suspecting drawn out, but don't know what is in your imagination.  You can use those physical sensations to communicate the character's feelings as a method to evoke them in your reader.

Another technique is a metaphor or a simile. Is wow being said like a fog horn? Is Wow being bugled like a moose during mating season? Is it blaring like a horn right before a crash? Think about what it sounds like or feels like then imagine substitutions to add greater substance to the page.